# Send multiple sms in Android

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I was making an app that could send multiple sms messages (all with the same text) to one recipient. Currently, the app has a pretty poor set up for sending 5 messages at once.

Here is what I used to send 5 sms messages. Is there a better way to send multiple messages, and a better way to store the messages in the users inbox? Because copying and pasting the same thing over and over is really messy. Thanks!

```
public void function1(int id){ 
            String phoneNo = phoneInput.getText().toString();
            String sms = textSMS.getText().toString();
            try {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.sentMessages), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                final boolean save = prefs.getBoolean("addvalues", true);
                if(save){
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();                       
                    values.put("address", phoneNo);                               
                    values.put("body", sms);
                    getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values); 
                    getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values); 
                    getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values); 
                    getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values); 
                    getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);  
                }
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.messageNotSent), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
```

Comment: What is the application? At first glance it seems somewhat like spamming software.

Comment: Why not using loops and arrays?

Comment: you make it messy. why you make so much repetition. As @abbath said use loops and array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting aside your application seems like a spam bot, here is how I would implement it.

Using a `for` or `while` loop is probably what you are looking for.

*(Where `noSends` is the amount of times you wish to send the message)*

```
public void sendMultiple(int noSends){ 

    String phoneNo = phoneInput.getText().toString();
    String sms = textSMS.getText().toString();

    try 
    {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        for(int i = noSends; i != 0; i--)
        {
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
        }

        if( prefs.getBoolean("addvalues", true) )
        {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("address", phoneNo);
            values.put("body", sms);

            while(noSends != 0)
            {
                 getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
                 noSends--;
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.messageNotSent), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    {
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.sentMessages), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this thank you. And the app is definitely not a spam bot, I'd never do that. Its just a small app to prank your friends, not to harm anyone.

Comment: @user1798956 
No problem.
If this works, the way to show other users this was correct and to say thank you, is to *check this answer as correct*.

Comment: There's one issue I found with this. Whenever you try to send the message (whether you pick a contact or not) it will say "Message sent!". And if there's an error, it will still say "Message sent!" but it will also say "Unable to send message". How can I make it so it only says "Message sent!" when it actually sends?

Comment: @user1798956 See the revised answer above.